# Linq Query unable to skip rows with null dates

Tags: c#, linq, casting

I have this linq query that needs to skip rows with null dates. However when a null date is encountered I get a casting error. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
var p = (from c in REPORT.GET_PERMITS_BY_ISSUED_DATE
      where (
      ((DateTime?)c.Submittals_Approval != null)
      && ((DateTime?)c.Submittals_Approval >= FromDate) 
      && ((DateTime?)c.Submittals_Approval <= ToDate)
       )
       select c.Permit_Bond_Amount).Sum();
```

Comment: what's the type of `REPORT.GET_PERMITS_BY_ISSUED_DATE.Submittals_Approval`?

Comment: Thanks guys I got it to work using this:

 var p = (from c in REPORT.GET_PERMITS_BY_ISSUED_DATE
                     where (
                     (c.Field<DateTime?>("Submittals_Approval") != null)
                     && (c.Field<DateTime?>("Submittals_Approval") >= FromDate)
                     && (c.Field<DateTime?>("Submittals_Approval") <= ToDate)
                     )
                     select c.Permit_Bond_Amount).Sum();

Comment: Brono, it is OK to add an answer to your own question. I did it for you now (as CW, so without rep). Maybe you can mark it as accepted in due time.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using this:

```
var p = (from c in REPORT.GET_PERMITS_BY_ISSUED_DATE 
where ( (c.Field<DateTime?>("Submittals_Approval") != null) &&
(c.Field<DateTime?>("Submittals_Approval") >= FromDate) && 
(c.Field<DateTime?>("Submittals_Approval") <= ToDate) )
select c.Permit_Bond_Amount).Sum();
```